# C# Check correct answer using dictionary function

Tags: c#, dictionary

For a school assignment I am having to create a driving theory test and have to use the Dictionary function.

```
Dictionary<int, QuestionsClass> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, QuestionsClass>();
        dictionary.Add(0, new Classes.QuestionsClass("Question", "Answer A", "Answer B", "Answer C", "Answer D", "Answer B"));
question = dictionary;
```

This is an example of the dictionary code where the last list item is the correct answer.

```
private void Option01Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radOption1.Checked)
        {
            SelectedAnswer = radOption1.Text;
        }
    }
```

I have four of these so the program knows which option has been selected as the answer. Once the user has selected their choice, they hit a submit button.

```
CorrectAnswer(); //check the answer is correct
CountQuestions++; //counts how many questions have been asked
```

This is part of the code that is in the submit button

```
if (!string.Equals(SelectedAnswer, question[RandomQuestion].Answer, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Correct = Correct + 1;
            }
lblScore.Text = Convert.ToString(Correct);
```

This is the function that keeps score of the correct answers.

Now for the problem. It may be very simple and easy to spot but this is my first C# application and I can't figure it out.

When the user selects an answer, the program always sees it as the correct answer.

Any help would be a HUGE help.

Thank You
Pierre

Comment: `Dictionary` is not a function but a collection.

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question with the code snippets you provided. Please post a **minimal working piece of code** to illustrate your problem

Comment: if the program thinks the answer is always correct, most likely the problem is in the CorrectAnswer() function, but before posting, remember to create a minimum complete and verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What if you **actually do** select the correct answer?  Does you program see that as a correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To evaluate if an answer is correct you perform the following comparison:

```
string.Equals(
  SelectedAnswer,
  question[RandomQuestion].Answer,
  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
)
```

This will be true the entered answer matches the answer of the question. However, for some reason you negate this comparison and uses that criteria to determine if the answer is correct:

```
if (!string.Equals(SelectedAnswer, question[RandomQuestion].Answer, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Correct = Correct + 1;
}
```

This swaps correct answers with incorrect answers and is not what you want.

So if my analysis is correct you need to get rid of the logical not operator (`!`) in front of the call to `string.Equals`.

Answer (score 0):

If statement should be:

```
if (string.Equals(SelectedAnswer, question[RandomQuestion].Answer, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Correct = Correct + 1;
}
```

You currently have it checking to see if the two answers are not equal and if so, increment by 1.